# Decreasing predictions from data w/ strictly upward trend?

Tags: python, time-series

I am using ARMA to make a time series forecast for the next 4 years. My data has a constant upward trend, but the prediction returns a downward trend, for some reason.

```
from pandas import Series
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.graphics.api import qqplot
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

dta = pd.read_csv('/Users/nsilverblatt/Downloads/test11111 - Sheet1 (4).csv', header=0)

x = dta['Total Revenue (in thousands)'].astype(float)

x.index = pd.Index(sm.tsa.datetools.dates_from_range('2011', '2016'))

print(x)
arma_mod = sm.tsa.ARMA(x, (2,0)).fit()

print(arma_mod.params)

my_predictions = arma_mod.predict('2016', '2020', dynamic=True)
print(my_predictions)
```

This is my CSV data, where the first line is Total Revenue in 2011 and the last one is from 2016.

```
Total Revenue (in thousands)

3399886
3897900
4595798
4965460
5308164
5520344
```

And here are the decreasing predictions:

```
2016-12-31    5.481435e+06
2017-12-31    5.465197e+06
2018-12-31    5.279251e+06
2019-12-31    4.975813e+06
2020-12-31    4.626178e+06
```

Comment: An easy way to remove a linear trend from a time series is to take the diff of  n and n - 1. For example,
`import pandas`;
`series = pandas.Series(range(10))`;
`(series - series.shift(1))`
`

Comment: @aquil.abdullah how would this work for my code? Are you saying this would make my predictions trend upward, which is what would make sense based off of the input (past) data?

Comment: No, I am saying that if you know that you have a trend in your data, you can remove that trend from the data using a difference. In fact pandas provides a diff function. If you know that there is a bias, you may want to apply the ARMA to your detrended data.

Comment: An ARMA model assumes a stationary series and predictions revert to the mean. You can either specify a linear trend or use an ARIMA model, i.e. with differencing.

Comment: @user333700 how do I specificy a linear trend?